# how to get formData file by input id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have formData which gets file based on input type

```
formData.append('idCard', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
```

Now I have several file input and getting file based on `type` of input isn't that ideal, i want to get my files based on input `id=""`

**How should i change my code above to get files by input id instead of input type?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an ID selector with `#`

```
formData.append('idCard', $('#idCard')[0].files[0]);
```

Replace `#idCard` with the actual ID of the input element.

You could loop over all the file inputs and append them all to `formData`

```
$("input[type=file]").each(function() {
    formData.append(this.id, this.files[0]);
});
```

Comment: would this work as well? `formData.append('idCard', $('input[name=idCard]')[0].files[0]);`

Comment: Yes, that would work. But the question says you want to do it by ID, not name. You can use any jQuery selector that will find the element.

Comment: i know i just try to gain more knowledge :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to change up your query so that it targets inputs exclusively with ids:

```
formData.append('idCard', $('input[id]')[0].files[0]);
```

Comment: what `first-of-type` means?

Comment: Straight from MDN: "The :first-of-type CSS pseudo-class represents the first element of its type among a group of sibling elements.". It basically grabs the first element of said type. In this case it'll select the first input.

Comment: so it means if i have 2 file input second one will be `second-of-type` ?

Comment: Please disregard my revised answer. To answer your question though, at that point you'd use `nth-of-type`. For the second input it would be `:nth-of-type(2)`.